# Как обновлять функцию через какой-то промежуток времени (aiogram)?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, бот

Бот должен выводить информацию о погоде при помощи команды /weather, вот код:

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['weather'])
async def get_weather(message: types.Message):
    code_to_smile = {
        "Clear": "Ясно \U00002600",
        "Clouds": "Облачно \U00002601",
        "Rain": "Дождь \U00002614",
        "Drizzle": "Дождь \U00002614",
        "Thunderstorm": "Гроза \U000026A1",
        "Snow": "Снег \U0001F328",
        "Mist": "Туман \U0001F32B"
    }

    r = requests.get(f"*здесь API-ключ из OpenWeather*")
    data = r.json()

    city = data["name"]
    cur_weather = data["main"]["temp"]

    weather_description = data["weather"][0]["main"]
    if weather_description in code_to_smile:
        wd = code_to_smile[weather_description]
    else:
        wd = ""

    humidity = data["main"]["humidity"]
    pressure = data["main"]["pressure"]
    wind = data["wind"]["speed"]

    await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text=
          f"<b>Погода в городе на данный момент</b>\n\n<b>Температура:</b> <em>{cur_weather}C° {wd}</em>\n\n"
          f"<b>Влажность:</b> <em>{humidity}%</em>\n\n<b>Ветер:</b> <em>{wind} м/с</em>", parse_mode='HTML'
          )
```

Как сделать так, чтобы бот обновлял информацию о погоде пока он запущен, если пользователь снова пропишет команду /weather?

P.S. Код запуска бота в другом файле

Comment: А разве сейчас он её не обновляет?